# How to get input text value

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I want to get a value in Java ADF using JavaScript. I tried many examples but got undefined or null value.

Do anyone know how to get the inputtext value in ADF using JavaScript?

And what are the configure?

Answer (score 1):

To find component you can use [method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23549_01/apirefs.1111/e12046/oracle/adf/view/js/base/AdfPage.html#findComponentByAbsoluteId_String_).
To get value from inputText use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/apirefs.1111/e12046/org/apache/myjs/trinidad/component/AdfUIEditableValue.html#getValue__).

```
var input= AdfPage.PAGE.findComponent("it1");
var value = input.getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

- Read value from inputText

> document.getElementById('pt1:r1:0:subform0base:userName::content').value
>   
>   **notice:**
>       How to get the id like this "pt1:r1:0:subform0base:userName::content" ?
>   just press "F12" and select you inputText in the browser usually,then you will see the id